# Is my mac filevault encrypted?

Tags: macos, big-sur, filevault

I recently encrypted my drive using filevault. However, the process to encrypt seemed to be practically instant, while for others it seems to take quite a while. I'm wondering if my drive was actually encrypted or not.

My computer is a Macbook Pro (M1, 2020), Big Sur 11.6.8

Answer (score 7):

Yes - Apple Silicon macs always encrypt the drive whether your account credentials are allowed (or needed) to decrypt it. Entangling a new encryption source happens instantly to enable and disable access to the always / already-encrypted contents. These changes happen to the volume metadata and Secure Enclave and don’t change masses of bits on the storage.

Here is a moderately deep technical paper on it with some nice summaries that are good reading.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/security/volume-encryption-with-filevault-sec4c6dc1b6e/web

At a high level the VEK exists and enabling FileVault establishes a KEK which is then needed to boot the OS since the drive needs your password before the OS can be decrypted and start up.

> Volume and metadata contents are encrypted with this volume encryption key, which is wrapped with the class key. The class key is protected by a combination of the user’s password and the hardware UID when FileVault is turned on.

[image: eked with FileVault enabled for hardware storage encryption]

Answer (score -3):

What happens *instantly* is that your Mac knows you want encryption to be turned on. It will then start encrypting, and eventually everything will be encrypted. How much is actually encrypted isn't visible to you, but it will continue encrypting whenever your Mac is running.

(Some people also have the problem that they use an encryption password and promptly forget it. Because of this I think you can turn encryption off without a password for some time).

Comment: This is not correct on macOS Big Sur. Only thing that changes is a new key gets entangled with the existing encryption keys and firmware enforces decryption after validating that new key. No data changes on disk as part of FileVault being enabled - only the decryption chain in the Secure Enclave or T2 chip secure storage gets an update.